# VBA Excel: set Sensitivity Label as Public

Tags: excel, vba, office365, excel-365

Good morning,
I would like your help. Is there any code with which I can set the sensitivity label as 'Business Use' for every new Excel file I open?

```
Workbooks.Add
'Define Sensitivity label as 'Public'
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:="C:\Users\" & Environ$("username") & "\Desktop\Test " & SR & ".xlsb" _
        , FileFormat:=xlExcel12, CreateBackup:=False
```

Could you please help me set the sensitivity label as Public?

thank you all !

I found the following code diplay the sensitivity id I guess.  I want to change the "GetLabel" to SetLabel I think....

```
Sub GetSensitivityID()
```

Dim myLabelInfo As Office.LabelInfo

Set myLabelInfo = ActiveWorkbook.SensitivityLabel.GetLabel()

MsgBox (myLabelInfo.LabelId)

End Sub